# How to delete rows with IDs in a specific range?

Tags: mysql

I tried looking for an answer to my question but I could not come up with anything to fit my case.

I'm simply looking for the correct sql statement to delete certain rows greater than a number but then I want it to stop at a certain point.

How can I do this?

```
DELETE FROM table_name where id >= 1043 and < 1101;
```

The above didn't work, it gave the error ...

> ## 1064 - You have an error in you SQL syntax;....for the right syntax to use near '< 1101' at line 1.

Comment: `where id >= 1043 and id< 1101` or use `between 1043 and 1100`

Comment: try .... and id < 1101;

Comment: thank you all. I tried `and where id ...` but didn't think to try `and id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table_name where id >= 1043 and id < 1101;
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't referencing your column again, so mysql doesn't know what you want to be less than 1101.

change this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name where id >= 1043 and < 1101;
```

to this :

```
DELETE FROM table_name where id >= 1043 and id < 1101;
```